# Collection View inside scroll view in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working in xamarin.forms. I have the collection view inside the scroll view. I know it is not a good practice but I am not in a position to change the whole code from scratch. Because of this, there are two scrolls on my single page, especially in IOS. I have gone through several articles, the below link is one of them but I could not access the whole code.

https://luismts.com/collectionview-inside-scrollview/

Is there any workaround? The blue arrows are my two different collection views and the whole page has inside Scroll View.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need Two scroll containers exactly? CollectionView has its own scroll could you explain your requirement a little, may be i can help

Comment: the workaround is to NOT do the thing that is universally considered a bad practice.  And what exactly does "could not access the whole code" mean?

Comment: I think you want to disable the collection view scroll like a vertical layout and having only the scroll view scroll bar right?

Comment: @LeandroToloza Yes I already turn off the visibility of the scroll bar of the collection view but I also want to remove the scroll effect.

Comment: @Json You are right. I am not fond of following bad practices. Now I am in a position where I just need to find some workaround in the existing code. The link which I have given explains the exact issue I am facing but the entire code is not there in the blog.

Comment: @FreakyAli I edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: what specifically is missing from the blog post?  Have you contact the author to ask?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Bindable layout instead of collectionview here. The bindable layout uses the parent scrollview and this will not create multiple scrollable layouts like collectionview.
Here is the official xamarin documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts